# Как вернуть значение из корутины в c++ 20

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20

Пытаюсь вернуть вектор из корутины, функция func1 успешно возвращает в func вектор из 3 элементов, но я не совсем понимаю для чего нужна функция return_value. При вызове co_return в нее передается тот самый вектор и он же возвращается, но из самой корутины возвращается пустой вектор.
Я не совсем понимаю, как работают функции ассоциированные с `co_return`, а именно

```
std::suspend_never final_suspend() const noexcept { return {}; }
std::vector<T> return_value(std::vector<T>&& value){
    return value;
}
```

Прочитал документацию и несколько статей, но все равно до конца не понимаю. Как правильно вернуть вектор из корутины?

Вот код

```
#include <chrono>
#include <coroutine>
#include <exception>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct std::coroutine_traits<std::vector<T>, Args...> {
    struct promise_type {
        void get_return_object() noexcept {}

        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() const noexcept { return {}; }

        std::suspend_never final_suspend() const noexcept { return {}; }

        std::vector<T> return_value(std::vector<T> &&value) {
            return value;
        }
    };
};

auto func1() {
    struct Awaiter {
        bool await_ready() { return false; };

        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> coro) {
            coro.resume();
        }

        auto await_resume() { return std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}; }
    };
    return Awaiter{};
}

std::vector<int> func() {
    int a = 5;
    auto v = co_await
    func1();
    co_return v;
}


int main() {
    auto a = func();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```